# Dinner table problem: with multiple tables

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Consider a party of $kn$ people and $k$ circular tables of size $n$. If they are seated randomly around the tables for two courses, what is the probability that no two people sit together at both courses?

This seems to be well studied for one table. For example see ftp://db.stanford.edu/pub/cstr/reports/cs/tr/80/829/CS-TR-80-829.pdf

Comment: Two clarifications please: 1) "seated randomly" means that the $kn$ people sit _at once_ in all $k$ tables (like "falling from the sky" directly in their seats all at the same instance? 2) "Sit together" means "sit in the same table" or "sit side-by-side in the same table"? Thank you.

Comment: It is sit side by side, next to each other.